# Modify key column to match the join condition

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on datasets (having 20k distinct records) to join two data frames based on a identifier columns `id_txt`

```py
df1.join(df2,df1.id_text==  df2.id_text,"inner").select(df1['*'], df2['Name'].alias('DName'))
```

`df1` has the following sample values in the identifier column `id_text`:

- X North
- Y South
- Z West

Whereas `df2` has the following sample values from identifier column `id_text`:

- North X
- South Y
- West Z

Logically, the different values for `id_text` are correct. Hardcoding those values for 10k records is not a feasible solution. Is there any way `id_text` can be modified for `df2` to be the same as in `df1`?

Comment: is it always a format of "(word)(space)(1 upper case)" and "(1 upper case)(space)(word)"?

Comment: We can ignore the case as we can apply lower function on the values.But the  space is common on both

Comment: Split the `id_text` by space into 2 columns and make the word as 1 column, the upper case char as 1 column and join condition with 2 columns works for you?

Comment: I was thinking more on hashing the values.Even the words are jumbled the hashing will remain constant.Any suggestion based on that will be great

Answer (score 1):

You can use a column expression directly inside join (it will not create an additional column). In this example, I used `regexp_replace` to switch places of both elements.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('X North', 1), ('Y South', 1), ('Z West', 1)], ['id_text', 'val1'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('North X', 2), ('South Y', 2), ('West Z', 2)], ['id_text', 'Name'])

# df1               df2
# +-------+----+    +-------+----+
# |id_text|val1|    |id_text|Name|
# +-------+----+    +-------+----+
# |X North|   1|    |North X|   2|
# |Y South|   1|    |South Y|   2|
# | Z West|   1|    | West Z|   2|
# +-------+----+    +-------+----+

df = (df1
    .join(df2, df1.id_text == F.regexp_replace(df2.id_text, r'(.+) (.+)', '$2 $1'), 'inner')
    .select(df1['*'], df2.Name))

df.show()
# +-------+----+----+
# |id_text|val1|Name|
# +-------+----+----+
# |X North|   1|   2|
# |Y South|   1|   2|
# | Z West|   1|   2|
# +-------+----+----+
```